# merge to dictionaries preserving different values

Tags: python, dictionary, merge

I am very new to python (python 3.2) and I have been struggling with a difficult problem. I have two dictionary with listed lists:

```
d1 = {
'mammals': ['dog', '5', 'cat', '4', 'mouse', '4', 'bat', '3'], 
'bird': ['robin', '8', 'bluejay', '6', 'goose', '5', 'cardinal', '5']
}
```

and

```
d2 = {
'mammals': ['cow', '5', 'horse', '4', 'cat', '4', 'dog', '3', 'beaver', '3'], 
'bird': ['bluejay', '9', 'goose', '8', 'eagle', '8', 'robin', '7', 'duck', '6', 'cardinal', '5']
}
```

In each dictionary, the pair name-number (for instance, `'dog', '5'`) correspond to how many instances of said item where present in the original data bases.

What I need is to merge the two dictionaries in a way that information about quantity preserved (again, in the example, the new dictionary would have `'dog', '5', '3'`. So that the merged dictionary would look somewhat like (I am not necessarily committed to nested dictionaries. I wrote it this way for easiness of visualization. The important thing is too keep the information):

```
d_merged = { 
'mammals': [{'dog': ['5', '3']},  {'cat': ['4', '4']}, {'mouse': '4'}, {'bat': '3'} , {'cow': '5'},
 {'horse': '4'}, {'beaver': '3'}],
'bird': [{'robin': ['8', '7']},  {'bluejay': ['6', '9']}, {'goose': ['5','8']},  {'cardinal': ['5',
 '5']}, {'eagle': '8'},  {'duck', '6'}]
}
```

I have tried various things with tuples, nested dictionaries and other possibilities, but the result has been a mess. It would mean a lot if someone could point me in a good direction to solve this. I thank you very much

Comment: Could you change the starting data structure? It would make more sense to have a list of (name, count) tuples, rather than lists of alternating name and count.

Comment: @jonrsharpe The original data structure has this format. I tried to change it in various ways before merging, but everything was unsuccessful.

Comment: Show us the code you've tried that failed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most readable way to do it is probably as follows:

```
output = {}
for key in d1.keys():
    output[key] = {}
    lst = d1[key]
    for name, count in (lst[i:i+2] for i in range(0, len(lst), 2)):
        output[key][name] = (int(count),)
for key in d2.keys():
    if key not in output:
        output[key] = {}
    lst = d2[key]
    for name, count in (lst[i:i+2] for i in range(0, len(lst), 2)):
        if name in output[key].keys():
            output[key][name] += (int(count),)
        else:
            output[key][name] = (int(count),)
```

In incomprehensible dictionary comprehensions, you can do it in two steps

```
d = {k: {a: int(b) for a, b in (v[i:i+2] for i in range(0, len(v), 2))} 
     for k, v in d.items()}
```

To turn them into dictionaries of dictionaries, e.g.

```
{'mammals': {'cat': 4, 'cow': 5, 'dog': 3, 'beaver': 3, 'horse': 4}, 
 'bird': {'goose': 8, 'duck': 6, 'eagle': 8, 'bluejay': 9, 'robin': 7, 'cardinal': 5}}
```

Then

```
output = {k1: {k2: (d1.get(k1, {}).get(k2), d2.get(k1, {}).get(k2)) 
          for k2 in set(list(d1.get(k1, {}).keys()) + list(d2.get(k1, {}).keys()))} 
          for k1 in set(list(d1.keys()) + list(d2.keys()))}
```

To combine the two.

Note that these methods both work even if there are different keys at the two levels (e.g. adding `d1['reptiles'] = {'lizard': 10}`).

Comment: Thank you so much for this, I really want to understand the second method you apply, but I am getting the error: `AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'keys'`. Any idea how is it happening?

Comment: You will get that error if you don't run the pre-processing step (`d = {k: {a: int(b)...`) on each of the source dictionaries; otherwise `d1.get(k1, {})` will return a list if `k1` is a key in `d1`, and lists (as the error message says) don't have keys.

Comment: Thank you again. You were right I did not replaced the names correctly at the last line, and that's why i get the mistake. Nonetheless, this solution doesn't do what I need, because it sums up the information on the initial dictionaries (for example, `'dog': '8'`) and actually I need to preserve the two pieces of information `'dog':['5', '3']`.

Comment: What if it's only in one dictionary? Do you want a zero for the other? Or just a single item in the list?

Comment: I really appreciate your help and your time. The ideal would be having just one value, but a zero would do as well!

Comment: Edited. The readable version gives you a 1- or 2-tuple, depending on whether or not it's in both dictionaries. The dictionary comprehension always gives a 2-tuple, with `None` for missing values.

Comment: @jorsharpe This is actually so nice!!! I am studying the different methods to learn from them, thanks a lot!!!!!!!

Answer (score 2):

first you can change d1 and d2 to be dictionaries that is easier to work with:

[note that list[::2] is sublist that holds all the item in the even indices, and list[1::2] holds the odds.]

```
>>> dc1 = {}
>>> for family in d1.keys():
        l = d1[family]
        dc1[family] = {l[::2][family]:[l[1::2][family]] for family in range(len(l)/2)}


>>> dc2 = {}
>>> for family in d1.keys():
        l = d2[family]
        dc2[family] = {l[::2][family]:[l[1::2][family]] for family in range(len(l)/2)}
```

now dc1 and dc2 are these:

```
>>> dc1
{'mammals': {'bat': ['3'], 'mouse': ['4'], 'dog': ['5'], 'cat': ['4']},
 'bird': {'goose': ['5'], 'cardinal': ['5'], 'robin': ['8'], 'bluejay': ['6']}}
>>> dc2
{'mammals': {'beaver': ['3'], 'horse': ['4'], 'dog': ['3'], 'cow': ['5'], 'cat': ['4']}, 
'bird': {'eagle': ['8'], 'bluejay': ['9'], 'goose': ['8'], 'cardinal': ['5'], 'duck': ['6'], 'robin': ['7']}}
```

and then you just need to combine them

```
>>> d_merged = {}
>>> families = set(d1.keys()+d2.keys())
>>> family2animals = {family:list(set(dc1[family].keys()+dc2[family].keys())) for family in families}
>>> for family in families:
        d_merged[family] = [{animal:dc1[family].get(animal,[])+dc2[family].get(animal,[])} for animal in family2animals[family]]
```